# javascript input format DD:HH

Tags: javascript, html

**Hello everyone,**

I need to create an input with validation, when the input format must be like this **DD:HH (Days:Hours)**.

When maximum days must be 365 and the hours 23:59, if the user entry bigger than return a zero (0) as default.

How can this be achieved using HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: You mean DDD:HH? Since days go from 1 to 365 and hours from 0 to 23

Comment: DDD:HH:MM it seems

Comment: @molamk exactly. Like as timepicker.

Comment: Please elaborate on your requirements and show what you tried. As you can see in the comments we are not actually sure of what you need. That can be helped with you creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find a dupe, but did not succeed.

Just convert to minutes and you are fine

As of writing it is very unclear what your requirements are. One field forcing user to type the colons? DDD:HH:MM?

You can also test the max attribute on keypress and cancel if too large

```js
var maxValue = 365*24*60, ddd, hh, mm;

function testVal() {
  var dddVal = ddd.value,
       hhVal =  hh.value,
       mmVal =  mm.value;
  dddVal === isNaN(dddVal) ? 0 : +dddVal;
   hhVal === isNaN(hhVal)  ? 0 : +hhVal;
   mmVal === isNaN(mmVal)  ? 0 : +mmVal;
   var val = (dddVal*24*60+hhVal*60+mmVal)
   console.log(val,maxValue)
   document.getElementById("error").textContent = val > maxValue ? "Too long time" : "";

}

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  ddd=document.getElementById("ddd");
   hh=document.getElementById("hh");
   mm=document.getElementById("mm");
  ddd.addEventListener("input",testVal);      
   hh.addEventListener("input",testVal);      
   mm.addEventListener("input",testVal);      
  testVal();
});
```

```css
input[type=number] { width:50px }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="ddd" min="1" max="365" placeholder="ddd" /> 
<input type="number" id="hh" min="1" max="23" placeholder="hh" />:<input id="mm" type="number" min="1" max="59" placeholder="mm" />
<span id="error"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `([0-2][0-9][0-9]|[0-3][0-6][0-5]):[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]`

```html
<input 
  id="ddhh" 
  pattern="([0-2][0-9][0-9]|[0-3][0-6][0-5]):[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]"
  placeholder="DDD:HH:MM"
  onchange="if(!this.checkValidity()){this.value=0}" 
  oninput="this.labels[0].innerHTML=this.checkValidity()?'valid':'invalid'">
<label for="ddhh"></label>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187820/discussion-on-answer-by-guest271314-javascript-input-format-ddhh).